# Why some Ajax calls are not visible in the console tab of firebug?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug

The last application I worked on, I was able to see the Ajax calls inside the console tab of "firebug" and clearly see the requests and responses and do some debugging.

This new application that I'm working on makes a lot of use of Ajax; however, the calls are not displayed in the console tab. My Ajax datatype is JSON.

Is this something related to the application? And what do you recommend to use for debugging when working with Ajax.

Thanks

Comment: Try this link... http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-debugging-with-firebug

Comment: Maybe its jsonp requests, go to the net tab and you should see them.

Comment: Firebug and Firefox version ? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138989/hidden-unvisible-ajax-request

Comment: @Musa Thanks, yes I can see them under the NET tab

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSONP requests are only seen under the NET tab.