# how to avoid exposing ajax calls in the client side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a project where many ajax calls are made to get data through API. When I open console, it is exposing the calls that are made to server. Is there any alternative way to call the php files hidden.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you mean by viewing network tab no. If you mean by output in console tab remove all console.* calls or don't use ajax at all ;D

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138989/hidden-invisible-ajax-request

Comment: Is there any alternative way to make server calls

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it.... from a man in the middle attach you can look at SSL

There is very little security you can get from hiding things from the world... you want to secure something make sure the server side is secure from any invalid data from the client side by using strong validations

Answer (score 1):

ajax is interpreted client side javascript run by the client's javascript engine. your calls to the server will always be readable to the client, one way or another. your security should not rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You have no control over the browsers behaviour. Why are you so paranoid that you want to do this.

The client (user) is at liberty to use sniffers.

Answer (score -1):

This is a feature by the browser. What you can actually do is to "disguise" your parameter names, encode(base64 or whatever fits your requirements here) your data as to not expose too much information.

Comment: you just cannot do it. you cannot impose security from client side

Comment: I did not even say he can do it? :) Is the comment above actually directed towards my comment or the topic?

Comment: All the data provider has control over is the Javascript. Just reverse engineer it. then any form of disguise can be found out.